# Need help in regular expression for notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Below is my sample text .

```
<ul>
<li><a href="www.google.com" target="blank">Google</a></li>
<li><a href="www.yahoo.com" target="blank">Yahoo</a></li>
<li><a href="www.bing.com" target="blank">Bing</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add an extra attribute in anchor tag with the value of hyperlink like below.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="www.google.com" target="blank" aria-label="Google">Google</a></li>
<li><a href="www.yahoo.com" target="blank" aria-label="Yahoo">Yahoo</a></li>
<li><a href="www.bing.com" target="blank" aria-label="Bing">Bing</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to do this using notepad++ regular expression. Appreciate your help !!

Comment: Then there's the famous "don't parse html with regex" thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Paulb, yep, but in notepad++ there is not much else available.

Comment: @trincot, you're right. I just cringe when I see people use the wrong tool. I suspect that OP wants notepad++ regex, because he is working a very large html file(s). and a large html file is a perfect breeding ground for regex not to work in. My life became much easier when I learned xslt for these situations.

Comment: @Paulb: *"a large html file is a perfect breeding ground for regex not to work in"*: It's a wrong *(and common)* idea. When this appends, that means the pattern is badly designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that all your  tags are correctly formed (no missing closing tag, no missing bracket, etc...). You can then do something like :
Replace :
`(<a[^>]*)>([^<]*)(<\/a>)`
by
`$1 aria-label="$2">$2$3`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/j5AlNp/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regular expression find/replace:

Find: `>([^<>]+)</a>`

Replace:  `aria-label="$1"$0`

#### Transforming Quotes

In comments you asked to also replace a single quote by a repeated single quote, in both the texts. This cannot be done in the same replace operation, but you could launch a separate one, that should be executed *before* the one above:

Find: `'(?=[^<>]*</a>)`

Replace: `''`

And then after this is done, you could apply the first replace operation.

Comment: Add started spase to the replace template

Comment: I typed the space, but apparently the code formatting does not render it. Ah, I managed to add a non-breaking space instead. Anyway, you got it ;-)

Comment: Hi trincot, I need to replace single quotes ' with double quotes '' only in hyperlink text. how can i update this one.

Comment: You'd need a second regex for that -- it is not possible to do both operations in one. So you want those quotes replaced only in the hyperlink text content, or also in the newly created `aria-label` attribute?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace both the places.                                                 
 <li><a href="www.google.com" target="blank" aria-label="Google's">Google's</a></li>                                                          the above should be display as                                                                <li><a href="www.google.com" target="blank" aria-label="Google''s">Google''s</a></li>

Comment: Well that would be invalid HTML, I suppose you want the attribute value to be wrapped in single quotes then? Or else the attribute value should be HTML encoded: `Google&quot;s`.

Comment: it is just sample. Need to update single quote with double quote in text. not html enocded.

Comment: Wait, now I see that you actually want two single quotes next to eachother, not a double quote. Did I get that right?

Comment: yeah, two single quotes. not double quote

Answer (score 0):

Use `(?<=www\.)(\w+)(\..+\")(?=>)` as a find template and `\1\2 aria-label="\1"` as replace template.

[image: Screenshot for example]

Click on **Replace All** button.